# angular filter nested array

Tags: arrays, angular, angular5

Hi I am developing web application in AngualarJS 5. I have one array and I am trying to update same array based on the input received. Below is my array.

```
[
 {
  checked:false,
  id:1109376510842,
  name:"info model",
  children:
  [
   {
     checked:false,
     id:5763308644187,
     name:'Configmodel'
   },
   {
     checked:false,
     id:5763308655187,
     name:'Devicemodel'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  checked:false,
  id:1109376580842,
  name:"data access",
  children:
  [
   {
     checked:false,
     id:57633458644187,
     name:'Configmodel'
   },
   {
     checked:false,
     id:57633084555187,
     name:'Devicemodel'
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I have one more input array which gives few details. Based on that array I want to update my parent array. My input object gives below details.

```
{
  parent: info model,
  data:{
  checked:true,
  id:5763308644187,
  name:'Configmodel'
  }
}
```

So based on the above object, I want to update my parent object. My object contains parent, this indicates which object from parent array has to be updated. Also object contains checked inside children. Now its true so I want to update checked inside children in info model of parent table.
I tried as below.

```
 if (node.hasChildren) {
                let copyCreate = Object.assign({}, node.data);
                copyCreate.checked = cb.checked;
                const targetIdx = this.createnode.map(item => item.name).indexOf(copyCreate.name);
                this.createnode[targetIdx] = copyCreate;
                }
                else {
                    let copyCreate = Object.assign({}, node.data);
                    copyCreate.checked = cb.checked;
                    const parent = this.createnode.find(e => e.name === node.parent.data.name);
                    if (parent) {
                        const child = parent.children.find(e => e.id === node.data.id);
                        if (child) {
                            child.checked = copyCreate.checked;
                        } else {
                            parent.children.push(copyCreate);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. You can do following in a service oder component:

```
updateObject(fullDataArray, updateObj) {
    // Find the parent 
    const parent = fullDataArray.find(e => e.name === updateObj.parent);

    // If the parent is set, search for the respective child entry
    if (parent) {
        const child = parent.children.find(e => e.id === updateObj.data.id);

        if (child) {
            // Updates the childs checked attribute
            child.checked = updateObj.data.checked;
        } else {
            // Add child if not exist
            parent.children.push(updateObj.data);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It does the trick. I updated above code. But problem is like createnode array i have updatenode array with same structure but different id's. Now whenever i tried to update createnode array it also updates updatenode array also. May I know the problem? this is happening only in child not in parent. I want to update only createnode array or updatenode array.

Comment: Are you sure both variable have different array instances?

Comment: yes because in the above code else section only giving problem.